# How to resolve a error in EventListener?

Tags: symfony, event-listener

I have a problem in redirect path according to role in FOSuserBndle.The problem is in :

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function generate() on a
>   non-object in.....

This is the event listener

```
namespace Register\UserBundle\EventListener;

///////////////////////////////




//////////////////////////////

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine; // for Symfony 2.1.0+
// use Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine; // for Symfony 2.0.x

/**
 * Custom login listener.
 */
class LoginListener
{
   protected $router;
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext */
    private $securityContext;

    /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
    private $em;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param SecurityContext $securityContext
     * @param Doctrine        $doctrine
     */
    public function __construct( SecurityContext $securityContext, Doctrine $doctrine )
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->em              = $doctrine->getEntityManager();


    }

    /**
     * Do the magic.
     * 
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_PATIENT')) {



 $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('demands'));            
     //this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));

        }

        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_THERAPIST')) {
            // user has logged in using remember_me cookie
             print_r("FFFFFFFFFFFFFTHERAPIST");
            die;
        }

        // do some other magic here
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $type = $user->getType()->getId();
        print_r( $type);
            die;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the router is not injected in your listener/service.

Listener class :

```
...
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class LoginListener
{
    protected $container;
    protected $em;
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, EntityManager $em, Router $router)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->router = $router;
    }
    ...
}
```

Service declaration :

```
my_bundle.my_listener:
    class: %my_bundle.my_listener.class%
    arguments: [ @service_container, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @router ]
```

Comment: i put it like you say but it redirect to default path configured in security.yml   and when i delete this line in security it don't redirect me to the right direction that i put it in EventListener :LoginListener

Comment: and this is the security.yml                               form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                default_target_path: /demands/Welcome

Comment: Well I haven't checked the logic behind your listener, I just helped you to fix the error. We will need a little more information about what you want to do. The $response object you create seems not to be used in the current state

Comment: i need to test the role of the user who will connect and if the user have a role patient i will redirect him to page1 else if he isn't i will redirect him to page2 .I use FOSUserBundle